# find the version of the underlying eclipse in jboss developer studio

Tags: eclipse, jboss-developer-studio

My current IDE is JBoss Developer Studio, which is just a wrapper over eclipse (apart from changing the logo and having a default JBoss server, i don't see any difference from eclipse - the UI and menus are identical)

What i need to know is how can i find out **the version of the eclipse** on top of which jboss dev studio is built?

Using  Help>About JBoss Developer Studio  says:

> Version: 9.1.0.GA
>
> Build id: GA-v20160414-0124-B497
>
> Build date: 20160414-0124

The readme.txt in the home folder says:

> Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio
>
> version 9.0.0, October 2, 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the installed software list in 'Help > Installation Details' ('Installed Software' tab).

This shows all the installed features. The Eclipse components should be something like 'Eclipse Platform'. The Version column gives the full version.

Comment: (for other readers) the exact location is the following: in  the Installed Software tab:   JBoss Developer Studio (Branded Product) >     JBoss Developer Studio (Core Features)  >       Eclipse Platform ; in the Version column i have 4.5.2 . which is Eclipse Mars 2

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Developer Studio 10.4 - based on Eclipse Neon.3 (Eclipse Platform 4.6.3) - is now available. Maybe you want to upgrade to the latest?

https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/